# Change columns in row - Data Table in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the following table

| Order | OrderDate | DeliveryDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | 12.12.2021 | 13.12.2021 |
| Truck | 13.12.2021 | 14.12.2021 |

now I want to create a table which has the following structure

| Order | Activity | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | OrderDate | 12.12.2021 |
| Car | DeliveryDate | 13.12.2021 |
| Truck | OrderDate | 13.12.2021 |
| Truck | DeliveryDate | 14.12.2021 |

So I want basically to change the columns into rows.

Do you have any suggestions or similiar threads?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table1 is in sheet1!A1:C3. Manipulating using index()&match() with int(), column() & row() used to 'call' cell value should do.

in Sheet2!A2 :

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$3,INT(ROW()/2))
```

in Sheet2!B2 :

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$C$1,MOD(ROW(),2)+1)
```

in Sheet2!C2 :

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$C$3,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(B2,Sheet1!$B$1:$C$1,0))
```

and drag downwards.

ref formula : https://exceljet.net/index-and-match

Please share if it works/not/understandable.